# How to count frequency of keywords (in csv file) in several txt files

Tags: python, regex, pandas, counter

I have a csv file including several keywords in one column. I would like to count the frequency of occurrence of these keywords in multiple txt files and write them in one csv file.

Keywords

- ifrs
- financial risk

Expected output

company names, ifrs, financial risk

XYZ company, 4, 5

My code below is very slow and counting each keyword separately. I need something more simple and efficient.

```
file_list = []
path = ["/folder1",
        "/folder2",
        "/folder3"]
        for i in tqdm(path):
        for filename in os.listdir(i):
        with open(os.path.join(i, filename), encoding='ISO-8859-1') as filedata:
            text=filedata.read()
            string = "".join(filedata.read().split())
            ifrs=sum(1 for match in re.finditer(r"\bifrs", text, re.IGNORECASE))
            financial_risk = sum(1 for match in re.finditer(r"\bfinancial risk", text, re.IGNORECASE))
            count=len(text.split())
            res=re.findall("data_(\d+)_", filedata.name)
            k=' '.join(res)
            file_list.append({'cik': k, 'ifrs':ifrs,'financial risk': financial_risk})
            dft=pd.DataFrame(file_list)
            dft.to_csv('Risk_Factor_word_count.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Except for some dead or useless code (`tqdm`, `string`, `count`), I am afraid there is little to gain here... You will have to read all the files and search keywords in them. Pandas will not help you for that part, but you failed to show how you were building a dataframe or writing the output csv file.

Comment: Hello I updated my code.

Comment: If the size of your files is small against the available memory, I still think that there is little to gain. If you exhaust the memory and start swapping, reading and writing line by line could save a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to tallying matching strings using boolean masking with pandas and numpy:

```
df = pd.read_csv('{}'.format(filename)) # For given 'filename' in your dir
for line in df.to_numpy(): # Convert each line into a 1D numpy array
    
    # Create boolean masks for a keyword in your keyword dictionary
    for keyword in keyword_dictionary:
        mask = numpy.isin(line[0].split(),keyword) 
        
        # Determine the amount of times keyword is found (True = 1)
        keyword_dictionary[keyword] += sum(mask)
```

You'll have to implement this chunk of code into a loop that iterates through your file directory. I'm assuming that you have a dictionary of keywords structured as follows:

```
keyword_dictionary: {
    'ifrs': 0,
    'financial_risk': 0,
    ...
    'your_last_keyword':0}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have 450 keywords. Does it mean that I should create 450 masks?

Comment: I guess I can't make clear codes in the comments section. I'll edit my reply instead!

Comment: My keyword dictionary is a csv file.

Comment: Ok, so the code above can now use your imported dictionary and update with corresponding instances of its keyword indices.